# Remove duplicate lines from textbox in .net 2.0

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I have a multiline text and i want to remove the duplicate lines in it. I use the following code to seperate the lines in an array.

```
string[] lines = txtPathological.Text.ToString().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But there is no command lines.Distinct(). Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me...

```
String[] lines = { "my line 1", "my line 2", "mhyline3", "lslfkdfkjdf", "my line 2", "my line 1", "my line 1", "LKDJF" };
List<String> list = new List<String>();
foreach (String s in lines)
{
    if (!list.Contains(s))
        list.Add(s);
}
```

"list" will then contain the distict lines, which you could get back to an array using:

```
String[] distinctLines = list.ToArray();
```

If this doesn't work, I'd suspect there's something about your lines that is fooling the Contains() method.  If so, you'd likely have to make a method to replace Contains(), local or extension, that would handle inspection of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var lines = txtPathological.Text.ToString().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var dLines = lines.ToList().Distinct();
```

Edit:

```
        string[] lines = txtPathological.Text.ToString().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<string> dLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (!dLines.Contains(line))
            {
                dLines.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no var in .NET 2.0 winforms.

Answer (score 1):

You could try :

```
string[] lines = txtPathological.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<string> templines = new List<string>(lines);
        List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < templines.Count; i++)
        {               
           if (!tempList.Contains(lines[i])) tempList.Add(lines[i]);
        }
```

TempList is your sorted list.
Hope it could help.

Comment: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for ToList()

Comment: Could you please try this one ?